# RX packets handle takes too long DPDK

Tags: c, ethernet, pmd, dpdk, pci-e

I'm developing my own DPDK PMD for an ethernet device which receives/sends packets through PCIe.
In order to develop my PMD, I'm using l2fwd application, which forwards packets from a physical port to my virtual one (which receives/sends packets through PCIe).

DPDK version - 20.11

Currently, I'm using only a single pair of TX/RX queues, so the application uses 2 lcores

- Lcore 0: RX port 0 TX port 1.
- Lcore 1: RX port 1 TX port 0.

Where port 0 is the physical one, and port 1 is the virtual one.

I send/receive packets using PCIe transactions (more than 1 transaction for every packet).
So, in order to send a packet from the physical port through the PCIe I issue one transaction, **wait** until the transaction is completed and then issue another one (it needs to be serial).

The problem I'm facing is that it takes time to upload packets I receive on tx_pkt_burst callback (Lcore 0), and I don't want the core to be stuck in my tx_pkt_burst callback for a long time every time it is been called (the core is stuck in my code instead of polling the physical core for new packets).

In order to fix it, I store the packets received in tx_pkt_burst in an array, and upload the packets using the second core (Lcore 1).
The second core polls my rx_pkt_burst callback, so I poll for new packets (and download them using PCIe), and upload packets received from tx_pkt_burst.

It goes something like that:

- Check for new packets to download.
- Start the download process if new packets are available.
- Check for packets to upload (received from tx_pkt_burst).
- Start the upload process if needed.

The code works, though I had to add spinlocks to some data since 2 cores will access the data.

I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to handle this.
Maybe a symmetric solution in which one core handles PORT0->PORT1 direction, and the second one handles PORT1->PORT0 direction.

I thought of using RTE alarms, something like that:

```
static bool alarm_set = false;

uint16_t my_eth_tx_burst(void *txq, struct rte_mbuf **tx_pkts, uint16_t nb_pkts)
{
  
  if (!alarm_set ) {
    rte_eal_alarm_set(1, my_alarm, NULL);
    alarm_set = true;
  }

 /* Save mbufs */
 /* Return number of saved mbufs */
}

static void my_alarm(void *param)
{
 /* Check for new packets to send */
 /* Check if any PCIe transaction completed, and start the next one if so */

 /* Call this function again in 1us */
 rte_eal_alarm_set(1, my_alarm, NULL);
}
```

That way, Lcore 0 will poll both the physical port for new packets, and my function to fire PCIe transactions.

What do you think?
Is there a common solution to handle this kind of problems?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please share the code snippet of packet tx-arrary (as it is not clear to me what is been done). Question - are you trying to calculate the latency involved in DPDK RTE_TX_BURST to actual PACKET EGRESS on the PCIe device? If so you should be avoid virtual interface (assuming pcap or tap PMD) as it also incurs overhead. Will you be able to rephrase and share diagram of your explanation too

Comment: Thanks for the reply @VipinVarghese.
Let me summarize the question, It takes time to handle packets in `tx_pkt_burst` callback, and part of this time is waiting for PCIe transactions to finish. I don't want to keep the core waiting in my function, I want to release it as soon as possible. Is there a "correct" way to cause the core to poll my tx_pkt_burst function? I could do it by calling `rte_eal_alarm_set`, but I'm not sure that this is the best way to do so.

Comment: thanks for the reply. It looks like you are stating `tx_burst` actually writes (`DMA`) the packet and its metadata content into NIC or ASIC buffer memory. If this is the assumption for physical PMD (intel, mellanox, braodcom) then I have to state this is not correct assumption. As mentioned can you please update your question with NIC, PMD, firmware and diagram. Note: completion Queue is introduced and exposed to notify the actual packet egress or drop in the ASIC|NIC. DPDK tx_burst call back is just a callback invoked for each call for tx_burst.

Comment: reason for updating the NIC and details for the new PMD is to understand whether it is simialr to xilinix QDMA, where one option to copy byte by byte to packet data into FPGA memory. If the hardware in use supports dma descriptor model with completion queue one can avoid this too.

Comment: I'm developing a NIC, which is based on DPAA2 HW (NXP). In order to develop my PMD I'm running l2fwd application to forward packets between the physical port (which is attached to the dpaa2 pmd), and a virtual one which is attached to my PMD, and sends/gets packets from PCIe. When my `tx_pkt_burst` callback is called, I start the DMA operations to send the packets through PCI. The point is that I need to wait for the DMA operaion to finish in order to do some more work. Is there a way to tell the core to poll my function instead of locking the core in my `tx_pkt_burst` until the DMA finishes?

Comment: thanks now it makes sense. especially `The point is that I need to wait for the DMA operaion to finish in order to do some more work`. Hence you are actually looking for something very similar to `completion queue` notification. As far the offical latest PMD, I do not think there is implementation of completion queue https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/dpaa2.html. But from what you describe you need `completion queue` notification and call back for processing similar to 5G SoC. I am not an expert on DPAA2, keep me posted will share if I find something.